variance of known finite population from all possible bootstrap sample means
A question I know has little practical interest but I was asked this and have been stuck for a day thinking about it.
If we take the set of all possible bootstrap samples size n from a small/finite population N and retain only the sample means, can we obtain the population variance? We of course have the sample means, so we can obtain the variance of the means and the mean of sample means.
let N = 10, n = 3; the bootstrap set of possible sample means is a size 220 set. We have 220 means of which the bagged mean is of course equal the true population mean. But how might we obtain the population variance from this? Is it even possible?

Of course: but how to show it?
The key is that bootstrapping is a red herring.  Let's generalize just a little and consider samples (with replacement) of size $k$ from any population or data generation process having a variance of $\sigma^2,$ where $k$ is arbitrary. Such samples can be considered collections of independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ having the same distribution as the population, whence
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2.$$
Yet, the mean of this sample is
$$M = \frac{1}{k}(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_k).$$
As you already know (or can readily show by invoking the bilinearity of covariance),
$$\operatorname{Var}(M) = \frac{\sigma^2}{k}.$$
Your question comes down to whether you can recover $\sigma^2$ from a sample of $M,$ and the answer should now be obvious: estimate the variance of $M$ from your sample and multiply it by $k.$  When your sample is the entire population of all bootstrap samples, you can estimate it exactly with no error, so employ that estimate.

@Friede It is generally understood that "$\sigma^2,$" when referring to a variance, is a number (not a matrix).  That tells us $X_i$ is a real-valued random variable.  However, the same argument presented here applies to vector-valued variables too, without any change at all: but one would use "$\Sigma$" to refer to their common variance.
